# Android soft keyboard pops up and hides automatically

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I have this strange issue where the soft keyboard keeps popping up and hiding out in my application.

It only happens on tablets, on the phone it works with no problem, only when running the app in a tablet this problem happens. I also tried it in real devices, the same problem occurs.

I searched a lot for other posts that have the same problem, but I couldn't find anyone else who have the same problem.

Here is a video of the problem: http://youtu.be/b9jJQzgxaIo

Here is the manifest code for this fragment:

```
<activity
        android:name="com.mapsaurus.panesexample.CreateAssignment"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_create_assignment" >
</activity>
```

I tried with and without `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"` and with and without `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible"` but without any luck.

I'm using [Android-PanesLibrary](https://github.com/Mapsaurus/Android-PanesLibrary), so the `EditText` field is inside a `SherlockFragment` not an activity, when it is in a normal activity, it works fine.

I hope someone have a solution for this.

Thanks..

Comment: Have you tried using the fragment on its own without the Panes Library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After I wrote the question, I found the solution in my own question.
This happens because it is a Fragment not an Activity, so I added `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` to the Activity that this Fragment is attached to, and it worked. I think the problem was because the keyboard talks with Activities not Fragments, I don't know if this is true, but I that's the explanation for it.
I hope someone will benefit from this in the future.

Comment: you add it to the activity or to the AndroidManifest.xml ?